# Passing parameters into a closure for setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, closures, document-ready

I've run into an issue where my app lives in an iframe and it's being called from an external domain.  IE9 won't fire the load event when the iframe loads properly so I think I'm stuck using setTimeout to poll the page.

Anyway, I want to see what duration is generally needed for my setTimeout to complete, so I wanted to be able to log the delay the setTimeout fires from my callback, but I'm not sure how to pass that context into it so I can log it.

```
App.readyIE9 = function() {
  var timings = [1,250,500,750,1000,1500,2000,3000];    
  for(var i = 0; i < timings.length; i++) {
    var func = function() {
    if(App.ready_loaded) return;
      console.log(timings[i]);
      App.readyCallBack();
    };
    setTimeout(func,timings[i]);
  }
};
```

I keep getting LOG: undefined in IE9's console.

What's the proper method to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: this could be a so much better question if you make it more generic, such as removing so many values from `timing` and all lines with `App`!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is happening because you are not closing around the value of `i` in your `func`.  When the loop is done, `i` is 8 (`timings.length`), which doesn't exist in the array.

You need to do something like this:

```
App.readyIE9 = function() {
  var timings = [1,250,500,750,1000,1500,2000,3000];    
  for(var i = 0; i < timings.length; i++) {
    var func = function(x) {
      return function(){
          if(App.ready_loaded) return;
          console.log(timings[x]);
          App.readyCallBack();
      };
    };
    setTimeout(func(i),timings[i]);
  }
};
```

Comment: This redefines the function in the loop. @VisioN's [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10855510/1269037) is more efficient.

Answer (score 11):

When your function gets called by `setTimeout` sometime in the future, the value of `i` has already been incremented to the end of it's range by the `for` loop so `console.log(timings[i]);` reports `undefined`.

To use `i` in that function, you need to capture it in a function closure.  There are several ways to do that.  I would suggest using a self-executing function to capture the value of `i` like this:

```
App.readyIE9 = function() {
  var timings = [1,250,500,750,1000,1500,2000,3000];    
  for(var i = 0; i < timings.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if(App.ready_loaded) return;
            console.log(timings[index]);
            App.readyCallBack();
        }, timings[index]);
    })(i);
  }
};
```

As a bit of explanation for who this works: `i` is passed to the self-executing function as the first argument to that function.  That first argument is named `index` and gets frozen with each invocation of the self-executing function so the `for` loop won't cause it to change before the `setTimeout` callback is executed.  So, referencing `index` inside of the self-executing function will get the correct value of the array index for each `setTimeout` callback.

Answer (score 3):

This is a usual problem when you work with `setTimeout` or `setInterval` callbacks. You should pass the `i` value to the function:

```
var timings = [1, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3000],
    func = function(i) {
        return function() {
            console.log(timings[i]);
        };
    };

for (var i = 0, len = timings.length; i < len; i++) {
    setTimeout(func(i), timings[i]);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/r56wu8es/

Comment: This will call `func` with `i` as a parameter, and pass its return value to `setTimeout`.  `func` needs to return a function.

Comment: You didn't fix it.  `func` still returns `undefined`.

Comment: You are missing `var func = function(x) {` from the original post.. well that is what Rocket is trying to point out.

Comment: Yes, it's time to go sleep :) Thanks, guys!

Comment: This answer is now essentially the same as [Rocket's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10855509/1269037) (a parametrized function). Delete maybe?

Comment: @DanDascalescu Nope. You don't need to redefine function in the loop. I have updated the code snippet to make the difference more obvious.