# A more graceful way of throttling jQuery $().each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use jQuery to `$().each` through inputs, make an AJAX call based on two of the inputs and update a third input. However, the AJAX call (Google Maps reverse geocoding) has a call limit, meaning I have to limit the number of requests I make per second.

I'm trying to throttle the `each` by calling a setTimeout with a timeout that increases by 2 seconds for each iteration, but it just calls them all at once. Any insights on what I'm doing wrong? I'm basing my approach on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202403/how-to-add-pause-between-each-iteration-of-jquery-each) but 
a few things- specifically the fact that the elements affected change with each iteration- make this a bit more complicated.

```
<button class="identify-locations">Identify locations</button>

<div class="row">
    <input class="address"></input>
    <input class="lat"></input>
    <input class="lng"></input>
</div>
<!-- the same thing over again 30 times -->

<script>
    $(".identify-locations").click(function(event){
        var time = 2000;
        $(".row").each(function(){
            if($(this).find(".lat").val() == '' && $(this).find(".lng").val() == ''){
                setTimeout( geocodeLocation($(this)), time);
                time += 2000;
            }
        });
    });

    function geocodeLocation(object, time){
        address = object.find(".address").val();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({address: address},
            function(results_array, status) {
                if(status == 'OK'){
                    object.find(".lat").val( parseFloat(results_array[0].geometry.location.lat()) ); 
                    object.find(".lng").val( parseFloat(results_array[0].geometry.location.lng()) );
                    updateCount();
                }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling setTimeout with a function that returns the result  immediately.

Instead do

```
if($(this).find(".lat").val() == '' && $(this).find(".lng").val() == ''){
 var $current = $(this);
 setTimeout(function() { geocodeLocation($current)}, time);
 time += 2000;
}
```

Also check out [Passing parameters into a closure for setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855473/passing-parameters-into-a-closure-for-settimeout)

Note that the useful .bind is not available in IE8/Safari5

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are calling the function geocodeLocation at:

```
setTimeout( geocodeLocation($(this)), time);
```

instead you are supposed to only point to its label. Therefore, it should be:

```
setTimeout( geocodeLocation.bind(null, $(this)), time);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `index` of `.each()`

```
 var time = 2000;
 $(".row").each(function(index){
   if($(this).find(".lat").val() == '' 
      && $(this).find(".lng").val() == '') {
        setTimeout(function() { 
          geocodeLocation($(this))
        }.bind(this), index * time);                    
   }
 });
```

Comment: Hmm, never seen that construct. Looks interesting. I wonder why I see a number object in the console and not a primitive... I will try that with a jQuery collection - that works. Wonderful - http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/36d7b2ar/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80346/discussion-between-guest271314-and-mplungjan).

Comment: Aha: bind isn't supported in IE8 and Safari5

Comment: Not sure. I am off my computer now