# Javascript console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at displaynone

Tags: javascript, null

I'm writing a simple javascript slider that is supposed to display a slide, then after 5 secs display:none for that slide, and show the next slide.  I get the console error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at displaynone."  Below is the content of the slider7.js:

```
window.onload = function () {

var imgid = [];

var numberOfSlides = document.getElementById("slide-container").childElementCount;

console.log("total slide count is: " + numberOfSlides);

for (i = 1; i <= numberOfSlides; i++) {
    console.log("here's the value of i: " + i);
    imgid.push("img-" + i);
}

console.log("The full contents of the array are " + imgid);


function displaynone() {
    document.getElementById(imgid[j]).style.display = "none";
}

for (j = 0; j < numberOfSlides; j++) {
    console.log("identify each image id in turn: " + imgid[j]);

    document.getElementById(imgid[j]).style.display = "block";

        window.setTimeout(displaynone, 5000);
    }

};
```

I wrapped the slider guts within window.onload to ensure all html objects are fully loaded.  I've also checked the HTML to ensure that the element IDs I'm styling exist:

```
<body>
    <div id="slide-container">
        <img id="img-1" src="005.jpg">
        <img id="img-2" src="006.jpg">
        <img id="img-3" src="007.jpg">
        <img id="img-4" src="008.jpg">
        <img id="img-5" src="009.jpg">
    </div>
    <script src="slider7.js"></script>
</body>
```

Relevant portions of console.log read:

```
The full contents of the array are img-1,img-2,img-3,img-4,img-5
identify each image id in turn: img-1
identify each image id in turn: img-2
identify each image id in turn: img-3
identify each image id in turn: img-4
identify each image id in turn: img-5
```

An observation is that the line of code below only generates the console error when wrapped in the window.setTimeout function:

```
document.getElementById(imgid[j]).style.display = "none";
```

If I remove this line from the function and simply put it below the line containing ' display ="block" ', it sets the inline display to none, but without any time delay.  Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

simply check out variable j
it's undefined in displaynone function.
use closure!

[Passing parameters into a closure for setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855473/passing-parameters-into-a-closure-for-settimeout)

+added

or you can solve it as declaring variable j as global

Answer (score 0):

Without using windows.onload try to execute the js fucntion like this way.

```
<body onload="your function">
```

use css to hide all the images in initial stage.